How to refactor the karate test to eliminate multiple calls?
Hi I am having a karate test. in the test i am making 4 requests to a service b and one request to service a . How can i refactor the 4 calls to service b in a compact way
the following is my test
@BcomRetry
Feature: Message Routing u

  Background:
    * configure ssl = true
    * configure httpVersion = 'http2'
    * def servicebBaseUrls = ['http://localhost:28090', 'https://localhost:28091', 'http://localhost:28092', 'https://localhost:28093']
    * def serviceaBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:28081'
    * configure retry = { count: 100 }
  Scenario: Test7   
    * def serviceb1BaseUrl = karate.get('servicebBaseUrls[0]')
    * def serviceb2BaseUrl = karate.get('servicebBaseUrls[1]')
    * def serviceb3BaseUrl = karate.get('servicebBaseUrls[2]')
    * def serviceb4BaseUrl = karate.get('servicebBaseUrls[3]')    
    * def serviceaBaseUrl = karate.get('serviceaBaseUrl')
    * def requestBody = read('sba-local-policy/request.json')
    * def expectedResponse1 = read('sba-local-policy/test7EndpointLookupResponse.json')
     
    * url serviceb1BaseUrl
    Given path '/service-b/v1/id'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And print response
    
    * url serviceb2BaseUrl
    Given path '/service-b/v1/id'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And print response

    * url serviceb3BaseUrl
    Given path '/service-b/v1/id'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And print response

    * url serviceb4BaseUrl
    Given path '/service-b/v1/id'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And print response

    * url serviceaBaseUrl    
    Given path '/service-a/v1/testLoadbalancer'
    And header Accept = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    And request requestBody
    When method post
    Then status 200
    Then match response == expectedResponse1  

thank you

This is one way of handling urls. There are other ways as well. Check out the Scenario Outline I have used. Also you can move the things mentioned in Background section to karate-config.js to make the feature file cleaner.
@BcomRetry
Feature: Message Routing u

  Background:
    * configure ssl = true
    * configure httpVersion = 'http2'
    * def servicebBaseUrls = ['http://localhost:28090', 'https://localhost:28091', 'http://localhost:28092', 'https://localhost:28093']
    * def serviceaBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:28081'
    * configure retry = { count: 100 }
    * def serviceb1BaseUrl = karate.get('servicebBaseUrls[0]')
    * def serviceb2BaseUrl = karate.get('servicebBaseUrls[1]')
    * def serviceb3BaseUrl = karate.get('servicebBaseUrls[2]')
    * def serviceb4BaseUrl = karate.get('servicebBaseUrls[3]')
    * def serviceaBaseUrl = karate.get('serviceaBaseUrl')
    * def requestBody = read('sba-local-policy/request.json')
    * def expectedResponse1 = read('sba-local-policy/test7EndpointLookupResponse.json')

  Scenario Outline: Handle Multiple urls
    Given url <url>
    And path '/service-b/v1/id'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And print response


    Examples:
      | url                       |
      | 'http://localhost:28090'  |
      | 'https://localhost:28091' |

    Scenario: Test 2

      * url serviceaBaseUrl
      Given path '/service-a/v1/testLoadbalancer'
      And header Accept = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      And request requestBody
      When method post
      Then status 200
      Then match response == expectedResponse1  


Actually i dont want to move service b calls using scenario outline . because that will make it a separate test .
